# Using Mustache to output values separated with character

Tags: mustache

Is there any elegant way to accomplish list of values separated by character (comma, forward slash etc.)?

> Rob, Jon, Dan, Paul

I am using [ICanHaz](http://icanhazjs.com/) JavaScript implementation of the Mustache syntax.

```
<script id="nameTemplate" type="text/html">
    <span>Name {{#names}}{{.}} {{/names}}</span>
</script>
```

But this will give incorrect result

> Rob, Jon, Dan, Paul,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no build in feature like that, so you can do like that:

Template:

```
<script id="nameTemplate" type="text/html">
    <span>Name 
        {{#names}}
        {{name}}{{^last}},{{/last}}                            
        {{/names}}</span>
</script>
```

Script:

```
var namesAsArrayOfObjects = {
    "names": [
      {"name": "Rob"},
      {"name": "John"},
      {"name": "Dan", "last": true}
  ]    
};

var user = ich.nameTemplate(namesAsArrayOfObjects);
$('#output').append(user);​
```

Result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/alexpetrov/VS2jQ/

Another solution, less elegant on my taste:

```
<script id="nameTemplate" type="text/html">
    <span>Name         
        {{#names}}{{#trimed}}{{.}}{{/trimed}}{{/names}}
        </span>
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

```
var namesAsArrayOfStrings = {    
    "_counter": 1,
    "names": ['Rob', 'John', 'Alice'],
    "trimed": function() {            
        return function(text, render) {                            
            var text = render(text) + 
(namesAsArrayOfStrings._counter != namesAsArrayOfStrings.names.length ? "," : "");
            namesAsArrayOfStrings._counter++;

            return text;            
        }
    }   
};

var user = ich.nameTemplate(namesAsArrayOfStrings);

$('#output').append(user);​
```

Comment: Wow, great answer Alex! I was little bit afraid that there isn't built-in solution for it. I think I'll use your first solution. Thanks!